# How to remove DC offset of the input signal without using an opAmp?

Tags: pulse, dc-offset

Below is a pulse train with a DC offset:

[image]

This will go to the circuit below as input.

[image]

The thing is this works well in simulation but in real I need to remove the offset of the input signal.

My question is:

How can I remove this DC offset without using another opAmp i.e. just by adding a component to the circuitry ect.? Is there an easy way?

Comment: Try to AC couple it?

Comment: how bout  R C values for that?

Comment: 2.7 zener diode in series to burn off the offset (and decrease the peak voltage too)?

Comment: @user16307: how about you first try yourself before consulting the free EE.SE design service?

Comment: Note to other members - FYI this related (still active) question from the OP, explains the source of this signal and is asking for help with that circuit: [Need help with current pulse input to an analog circuit](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/241025/)

Comment: @SamGibson: yeah, he is known for asking lots of questions in a row that would stack on top of previous answers or even answered by those

Comment: @PlasmaHH 100n 100k AC coupling seems fine in simulation. Thank for insight.

Answer (score 1):

**Careful - my answer is only valid for low duty cycle signals as shown above**

You can use a simple RC high pass filter in front of R3 as your comparator input resistance is quite high.

DC offset is basically Voltage with 0frequency so, the high pass will filter it out!

Something like 47n / 220k will do the job (depending on other design considerations the values may vary!

[image]

Comment: thanks mate, i used 100k 100n, is there specific reason you chose those R C values?

Comment: @Karl Note that this works in this case only because the duty cycle is very low. If it was 50-50, the output signal levels would start to go down cycle after cycle and you'd end with a signal between -2.5 and +2.5V. To overcome this, you need a similar circuit but with a diode.

Comment: @dim - You are right! Out of his question I was assuming that the input signal is in a duty cycle region as shown. With higher duty cycles the low frequency content is getting more and the RC filter will not work! I will add to my answer that it's only valid for low duty cycles.

Comment: Input signal will be between 200Hz and 1000Hz and the ON time is fixed by timer. So far the priblem looks solved for that range of interest

Answer (score 1):

There has been a similar question recently: [Solution for adding around 60V dc-offset on digital signal(0 and 5v) of 10MHz frequency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/240911/solution-for-adding-around-60v-dc-offset-on-digital-signal0-and-5v-of-10mhz-fr/240915#240915)

Except you want to *remove* some offset (not add), so the circuit is a little bit different, but the principles are exactly the same (and well described in this other answer - the only difference is that the capacitor is charged when the signal is at high level, not low).

Here it is:

[image]

That will lead to a signal that will swing between 0.5V and 5.5V (due to the diode voltage drop). The advantage compared to a RC filter is that the levels won't change depending on the duty cycle.

Comment: could you also provide a diagram for the DC offset removal case if possible?

Comment: But... I did put the schematic, didn't I ?

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you meant that was adding offset. Thanks but what could be V2 in real? It should be voltage coming from a voltage divider or a voltage regulator? That kind of confuses me if I implement this circuit.

Comment: Ok, maybe it is not that clear, if you're not used to LTSpice. Sorry. V2 is the 5V supply (the "5" number below is the voltage). The "PULSE" voltage source V1 on the left is your input, and the unterminated wire going to the right (from the diode anode) is your ouput.

Comment: Alright I meant in my case there will be only one power supply and that will be 12V. So can I make that 5V from 12V by a voltage divider? Would that be ok?

Comment: Mmh. That is risky. Where does the signal go after? Does it need to sink/source a lot of current?

Comment: See the second picture in my question. There is a circuit. You can see where the input goes and rest.

Comment: See the second picture in my question. There is a circuit. You can see where the input goes and rest. Input in this case is from Rshunt which converts current to voltage signal

Comment: Because for some software reason I dont want offset at the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41245/discussion-between-dim-and-user16307).

Comment: sorry for some reason i couldnt login chat, im on mobile now. But the ac coupling works for now.. the input's max duty cycle is %10 at 1000Hz and since the ON time is always fixed around 100us the duty cycle even less than %10 at other frequencies.

Comment: Ok: Here is what I wrote on chat: I was wrong, you can't use a voltage divider, or you'll end up with the same problem as in KarlKarlsom's answer: it seems the signal will be offset depending on the duty cycle. But maybe this is not a problem...

Comment: Now, I still don't uderstand the problem with changing the comparator thresholds. Does this signal feeds something else than the comparator input ? You talk about software. Where is this software running ?

Comment: it is very long story basically I extend the current spike input ON times for DAC to detect rising edges since tha DAC's sampling rate is not enough for the current pulse. Software side is another story. I cannot modifiy it so I modify the signal to DAC

Comment: So the offseted signal is also sent to a DAC, in addition to the comparator, or something like that ? Where exactly is used this signal ?

Comment: You re right about tresholds but the thing is in simulation it was ok with current tresholds but in real it didnt work. i will try again and give feedback later,

Comment: I gave up investigating on this. Very peculiarly when I AC couple it works but if I dont it doesnt work "in real life". But both without AC coupling and with AC coupling works good in simulation. It is also not related to treshold voltages.So Im fine with AC coupling for this particular application. I just dont know the reason why. But thanks for the assist.

Comment: Well, if you manage somehow to make it work "in real life", everything is good, then, I guess. I can't give you an explanation, though, as I don't know the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Well its crude, less than 100% accurate , and your results will vary with load, but you might get away with just adding 5 or 6 silicon diodes to the output, or maybe even a yellow LED or similar combination along with one diode. If you need a little more stability and fine tuned accuracy, an LM137 negative voltage regulator along with a trim pot for setup might offer a way to create a "return path" for the pulse that sits right at the desired offset. That new "floating" ground would then have to be the reference for any additional circuits using that pulse. And finally, though you said you didn't want to resort to an op amp, consider that 1/2 of a dual op-amp might take the place of the LM317 you're already using.